How to return iterator from function in C++
I'm trying to create a 'filtered' iterator to allow me to iterated over a list, where I only return values that match a particular filter.   I seem to be running into an issue, however, where an iterator becomes corrupted when I return it.   I'm new to C++, so I'd appreciate if someone can fill me in on the proper paradigm on how to do this.  I have the following:
class filteredIterator {
public:
    const std::list<const char *>           *myWords;
    std::list<const char *>::const_iterator  myIt;
    char filter;
};

filteredIterator
begin(const std::list<const char *> words, char filter) {
    filteredIterator rt;
    rt.myWords = &words;
    for(rt.myIt = words.begin(); rt.myIt != words.end(); ++rt.myIt) {
        const char * word = *rt.myIt;
        if (word[0] == filter)
            break;
    }
    printf("returning: %p: %s\n", *(rt.myIt),*(rt.myIt));
    return rt;
}

void test123() {
    std::list<const char *> words;

    words.push_front("CAT");
    words.push_front("BAT");
    words.push_front("BOB");

    filteredIterator fit;
    fit = begin(words,'B');
    printf("got: %p\n", *(fit.myIt));
}

but, it appears as though my iterator becomes corrupted as soon as I return from begin -- I have the following output:
returning: 00007ff78fe6012a: BOB
got: feeefeeefeeefeee

I'm guessing that the destructor of the iterator is killing things, but I'm not sure how to properly get around this (while keeping filteredIterator abstracted).

Very important in C++ to realise that when you write void func(T p); T a; func(a); that p is a copy of a, i.e. there are now two objects. If you want p to refer to a you should use a reference void func(const T& p) .... Now there is only one object and p refers to that object.

Aside: you don't need a pointer to the list, you need a current and an end iterator. I would also turn begin into a constructor for filteredIterator, and provide increment and dereference

@Caleth -- Thanks for the tips.  (again, new to C++ so all tips are very welcome).  What would the advantage of storing the end iterator over a pointer to the list be?

The issue you're encountering with the filteredIterator is due to the misuse of the iterator and the list. Specifically, the begin function is taking the list by value instead of by reference. This causes a local copy of the list to be created, and the iterator is pointing to elements of this temporary list, which gets destroyed when the function returns.
To fix this, you should pass the list by reference to avoid copying, and ensure that the iterator remains valid. Additionally, you should also handle cases where the filter doesn't match any elements in the list, to avoid dereferencing an invalid iterator.
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class filteredIterator {
public:
    const std::list<const char *>           *myWords;
    std::list<const char *>::const_iterator  myIt;
    char filter;
};

filteredIterator
begin(const std::list<const char *> &words, char filter) {
    filteredIterator rt;
    rt.myWords = &words;
    for(rt.myIt = words.begin(); rt.myIt != words.end(); ++rt.myIt) {
        const char * word = *rt.myIt;
        if (word[0] == filter)
            break;
    }
    if (rt.myIt != words.end())
        printf("returning: %p: %s\n", *rt.myIt, *rt.myIt);
    else
        printf("returning: end iterator\n");
    return rt;
}

void test123() {
    std::list<const char *> words;

    words.push_front("CAT");
    words.push_front("BAT");
    words.push_front("BOB");

    filteredIterator fit;
    fit = begin(words, 'B');
    if (fit.myIt != words.end())
        printf("got: %p\n", *(fit.myIt));
    else
        printf("No word starting with the filter found.\n");
}

int main() {
    test123();
    return 0;
}


Like the others say, the issue you are having is copying the list into the begin() function.
Here is some code that should work for you.
When run it outputs:
BAT
BOB

#include <list>
#include <cstdio>

class FilteredIterator {
private:    
    std::list<const char *>::iterator mItr;
    std::list<const char *>::iterator mEnd;;
    char mFilter;
public:

    // prefix increment
    void operator++() {
        ++mItr;
        while( mItr != mEnd && !match() ) {
            ++mItr;
        }
    }

    const char* operator*(void) const   {
          return *mItr;
    }

    bool operator!=(std::list<const char *>::iterator other) {
        return mItr != other;
    }

    bool match() {
        return (*mItr != nullptr) && (*mItr)[0] == mFilter;
    }

    FilteredIterator(std::list<const char *>::iterator begin, std::list<const char *>::iterator end, char filter) :
        mItr{begin},
        mEnd{end},
        mFilter{filter}
    {
        if( !match() ) {
            ++(*this);
        }
    }
};

void test123() {
    std::list<const char *> words;

    words.push_back("BAT");
    words.push_back("CAT");
    words.push_back("BOB");

    FilteredIterator fit = FilteredIterator(words.begin(), words.end(), 'B');

    for( ; fit != words.end(); ++fit) {
        printf("got: %s\n", *fit);

    }
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    test123();
    return 0;
}

